# Configuring SSO using OAuth2.0 for multiple targets in iOS app

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, target

I am developing an iOS app with multiple targets: dev, prod, QA and stage. The app has SSO login OAuth2.0 authentication.

SSO provider have two servers: dev.com and prod.com.
I am planning to use dev.com for qa, stage and dev and for prod target prod.com.
to build login URL.

My question is: How can I construct the URL for multiple targets using client ID and redirect URI?
To simply, should I use separate client IDs for each target? or keep the same Client ID and use different redirect URI based on unique bundle ids for each targets?

Thanks guys in advance. Could not find any answer for iOS app on google.

Answer (score 0):

After a considerable and fruitful amount of research, I got my answer. Just posting to help if anyone had the same issue and kept googling and wondering how to solve it.

It is better to keep the client Id same and change the redirect URIs based on the target's bundle IDs.